# ListPicker fullscreen list

Tags: windows-phone-7, listpicker

In my opinion, ListPicker list items are unacceptably small tap targets; certainly their height is smaller than the minimum size recommended by the style guide Microsoft published, and fact that Microsoft has taken to presenting the list full-screen in a much larger font suggests that I am not alone in holding this opinion.

I would like to use this full-screen big-font presentation in my own UI designs. I have tried specifying a DataTemplate (as a static resource) but it didn't seem to have any effect, although I'm pretty sure it is processed because when I made a typo in the resource name the compiler complained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using ListPickerItem objects for the items. This works until there are enough items to trigger Full mode and then it barfs.

If I import the System namespace and use String objects, everything's hunky dory. Supplying a DataTemplate and binding to something also works.

I think I have found a bona fide bug, but one with a trivial workaround: don't use ListPickerItem.

Answer (score 2):

On what basis do you say that the item tap target size is too small? Is this personal opinion or based on user feedback?

If you don't like default style of the ListPicker then retemplate it.

You can use the `ItemCountThreshold` property to control whether FullMode is always used or not (set it to 0).

You can also apply a full mode template to increase the touoch target size of what is displayed there.

Comment: When I try your suggestion of setting ItemCountThreshold to 0, my phone throws an exception "The parameter is incorrect" when the list is shown. I am using WP7.1 beta 2

Comment: It appears that it's actually the display of "Full" mode that causes the exception. Setting the mode explicitly, putting a lot of items in the list, or setting the threshold, all three produce "The parameter is incorrect". This happens irrespective of whether I try to template the picker.

Comment: You never mentioned an exception previously. Is this part of the same question? If so, have you got a repro?

Comment: OK I've worked up a repro, now I need somewhere to send it. I didn't mention the exception to begin with because I thought it was an ID10T error.